# Problem with equation derivation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, machine-learning

I'm studying support vector machines and the book I'm using states in one particular part the following:

We know that: 
$$\vec{y} = \vec{x} + v\vec{w}$$ and that $$|\;\vec{y}-\vec{x}\;| = 2M$$ and so we can compute that:

$$M = \frac{1}{2\:|\;\vec{w}\;|} = \frac{1}{2\:\sqrt{\vec{w}\cdot\vec{w}}}$$

My question is how did the author get this result? These are the only steps he shows, but I would need more details about what happened when deducing the value for $M$?

Here is a picture which will give more information:

[image]

Here is also the part in the book where I get confused, in case it helps (note that the notation is different but idea the same):

[image]

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: If you're going to include scanned in pages from a book, at the VERY least you should include a reference to the book.

Comment: Okay :) Machine learning, Stephen Marsland pages 121-122

Comment: You may provide more context on $v$ to0, because with the info above I could get only this:

Since $\mathbf y = \mathbf x + v \mathbf w$, it's obvious that $\mathbf y - \mathbf x = v\mathbf w$, and therefore $|\mathbf y - \mathbf x| = v |\mathbf w|$, on the other hand $|y - x| = 2M$, so $2M = v|\mathbf w|$, and therefore $M = \frac 12 v |\mathbf w|$. If you want to get $M =\frac 1{2|\mathbf w|}$, then you need to require that $v = \frac 1{|\mathbf w|^2}$.

Comment: @Kaster Thank you for your answer :) There is no other mention about the value of $v$ before or after in the book. All the information that is given I have posted :( "$v$ is some distance along the line". This is all the author gives. The line I presume is in the direction of $\vec{w}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVM, we only consider the margin for the "support" vectors $x$, i.e., those vectors satisfying $w\cdot x = \pm 1$. Thus the margin (distance) is $$\frac{|w\cdot x|}{\|w\|}$$

which is $1/{\|w\|}$. In your case, $y = x + v w$, and both $x$ and $y$ are support vectors on either side. WLOG, suppose $w\cdot x = -1$ and $w\cdot y = 1$. Thus,

$$w\cdot y = w\cdot x + v\|w\|^2$$

$$1 = -1 + v\|w\|^2$$

which gives $v = 2 / \|w\|^2$. On the other hand, $\|y-x\| = v\|w\| = 2M$, we thus have $M = 1/\|w\|$. I don't think $M$ has a $2$ in the denominator, since $v$ already considers the (double) distance from $y$ to $x$, and $M$ is the single sided distance.